Replace/Update the NextJS page Chunk Path
I want to Replace/Update the NextJS page Chunk Path.
https://localhost:3001/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-371116135d6e8e9c.js
I want to update that path to
https://localhost:3001/headless-architect/_next/static/chunks/pages/index-371116135d6e8e9c.js

Needed the help how can I achieve this in NextJS framework. I have try to search this on NextJS forum, but did not find any relevant solution.

You need to create the middleware.js file in your repo. Then, you can use this code:
import {NextResponse} from "next/server"

export function middleware(request) {
    if (request.nextUrl.href.includes('/headless-architect/_next/')) {
        return NextResponse.rewrite(
            request.nextUrl.href.replace('/headless-architect/_next/', '/_next/')
        )
    }
}

After that, add to your next.config.js use this code assetPrefix:'/headless-architect' like below:
const nextConfig = {
  basePath:'',
  trailingSlash: true,
  assetPrefix:'/headless-architect',
}

module.exports = nextConfig

